# want to transform a html and css file, in just one html file with css include in each tag

Tags: html, css

I have created a newsletter template with 1 HTML file and 4 CSS file. But the CSS is not linked when I send the newsletter. So I want to create a single HTML file with the CSS included directly in each tag. For each CSS tag I ha use in the HTML, I want that all the real value of this tag in the CSS file, to directly in the HTML tag. How can I do that?

## Old code

### CSS code

```
<style>
.mycss{
    width:100px;
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

### html code

```
<html>
    <div class="mycss">
      //some code
    </div>

</html>
```

## I want that to become

### CSS code

### html code

```
<html>
    <div style="width:100px; color: red;">
      //some code
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: no feedback... :/ why ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS Inliner such as [Mailchimp's CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) to accomplish this.

This is the process I use for newsletters that I write:

1. Copy and then paste the CSS from your various CSS files between the `<style></style>` tags in your html file
2. Copy and then paste all the code from that file into [Mailchimp's CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)
3. Click **Convert**
4. Copy and use the resulting code which now has with your CSS inlined.

Comment: Hello, i have try your solutions, it's work for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Would not you be looking for something from that?

```js
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText )
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].cssText )

/*
for (let styl of document.styleSheets )  {

    for (let rules of styl.cssRules){
        console.log( rules.cssText )
    }
}
*/
```

```css
.class01 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.class02 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:300px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class01">MyDiv 01</div>

<div class="class02">MyDiv 02</div>
```

Comment: No is not what i'm talking about. I have try the mailchimp solutions up there and is working